# Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Session::sess_destroy() 1.7.2

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

My current version of ci is 1.7.2 but ehen i am using

```
            $this->session->unset_userdata('uid');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('email');
            $this->session->sess_destroy();
```

in my controller an below shown is my class controller

```
      function Account()
{
    parent::BEV_Controller();   
    $this->load->model('facebook_model');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
}
```

Comment: but when i am removing sess_ from sess_destro... no error is shown and still session remains active

Comment: session should be loaded automatically in autoload.php not in every controller

Comment: i have removed it from controller still man no progress

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to destroy the session also, you have to load `$this->load->library('session');`

That should be the reason,

So load session library automatically, It's more convenient rather than calling `$this->load->library('session')` every where.

It's in application/config/autoload.php

Comment: $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session','encrypt','form_validation');                                          i have loaded session library but its not working

Comment: did you define the encryption key? in the config.php,

$config['encryption_key'] = 'job#hunt9675@wilk$5875';

Comment: u got my mistake Unicorn... i didn't defined the encryption key... can i take it as any string or some specified?

Comment: i used a 10 lettered encryp key... but it ruined whole my view.... so i replaced it with a null one as it was earlier

Comment: ummm, That's strange bit, That's the normal way the session works. It's bit difficult to figure out the error without seeing the code. Just use $this->session->unset_userdata('email'); and see what happens. Did you read the CI user guide on Session? http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: i had n also looking from the link that you are providing...... well its quite strange for me too... y its not working.

Comment: Did $this->session->unset_userdata('email'); work alone ? without $this->session->sess_destroy();

Comment: ok, Check if your Session variables are present? print_r($this->session)

Comment: CI_Session Object
(
    [flash_key] => flash
    [object] => Account Object
        (
            [_ci_scaffolding] => 
            [_ci_scaff_table] => 
            [config] => BEV_Config Object
                (
                    [uri_protocol] => AUTO
                            [url_suffix] => 
                            [language] => english
                            [charset] => UTF-8
                            [enable_hooks] => 
                            [subclass_prefix] => BEV_

Comment: Friend, Set some session variable and check if it's value is there. not just print_r($this->session).

Comment: [user_model] => User_model Object
                        (
                            [user_id] => 
                            [full_name] => 
                            [pwd] => 
                            [fb_uid] => 
                            [email] => 
                            [_parent_name] => User_model
                            [_ci_scaffolding] => 
                            [_ci_scaff_table] => 
                            [config] => BEV_Config Object
                                (                                  gettingg this one

Comment: Just wanted to check if session variables are set, bz you can't unset or destroy without setting them.  So using $this->session->set_userdata('email'); set the session variable and check if exists.

Comment: email,fb_uid are both returning null after setting them